# Combine UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput with UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress

Tags: iphone, ios, email, authentication, xamarin.ios

Is there any way of displaying a `UIAlertView` with Login/Password text fields, so that the keyboard type is of type `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`?

I use a `UIAlertView` as follows:

```
var alertView = new UIAlertView("Login".Translate(), "", null, "Cancel".Translate(), "Login".Translate());
alertView.AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.LoginAndPasswordInput;
```

or, in Objective-C:

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Title"
                          message:@"Message"
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
[alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
```

but all user names of my app are e-mail addresses, so I'd like to have the keyboard of the login textfield as an e-mail address keyboard, i.e. a `UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it. You can get the textfield of the `UIAlertView` and set the style there:

```
alertView.GetTextField(0).KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress;
```

Obj-C:

```
[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```